# Seeking Programming Examples

Tags: discussion

Does posting a question that seeks programming examples meet the qualifications of an OK question on stackoverflow?

Thanks for the answers. The question I had in mind was asking for a pointer to Django / javascript examples.

Comment: give us the sample question here. probably not.

Answer (score 2):

In and of itself, such a question has no particular qualities that make it obviously on topic or off topic.

It will depend on the actual question asked - I'm quite certain some programming example questions would be fine, and some would not.

Think about the question you want to ask, then test it against the FAQ:

It should generally cover:

> - a specific programming problem
> - a software algorithm
> - software tools commonly used by programmers
> - matters that are unique to the programming profession

and it should not be one where:

> - every answer is equally valid: “What’s your favorite ______?”
> - your answer is provided along with the question, and you expect more
>     answers: “I use ______ for ______,
>     what do you use?”
> - there is no actual problem to be solved: “I’m curious if other people
>     feel like I do.”
> - we are being asked an open-ended, hypothetical question: “What if ______
>     happened?”
> - it is a rant disguised as a question: “______ sucks, am I right?”
>
> If your motivation for asking the
>   question is “I would like to
>   participate in a discussion about
>   ______”, then you should not be asking here. If your motivation is “I would
>   like others to explain ______ to me”,
>   then you are probably OK. (The above
>   section was adapted from MetaFilter’s
>   FAQ. For more detail, see six
>   guidelines for great subjective
>   questions.)

Answer (score 2):

I think there are two points of view.

If you seek just learning examples for some technology you can ask the question but you will get faster response if you simply use google. Because of that you should also show links to examples you have already found and perhaps little bit explain why they don't fit your needs. Otherwise you can expect some bad feedback.

Another case is asking for codes to your tasks / homeworks. That is something you should rather not ask at all **unless you also provide what did you already try and where you have a problem.** Simply questions like: *I must do A,B,C using D,E please tell me how to do it?* or *I need to do A,B,C using D,E please give me some codes.* are not welcome.

Always show what you tried or where you failed and you can expect answers. If you just ask without any invention you can expect downvotes and closing your question.